# Vastly different runtime when evaluating $\mbox{}_3 F_2$

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions

This question is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270647/difficulties-evaluating-the-generalised-hypergeometric-function-mbox-3-f-2?noredirect=1#comment675579_270647).

I am interested in numerically evaluating the hypergeometric functions:

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 3, n/2}, {1 - m, 1 + m}, x]
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 2, n/2}, {1 - m, 1 + m}, x]
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1, n/2}, {1 - m, 1 + m}, x]
```

It seems that the first two take substantially longer to evaluate. For example, with $x=99/100$, they take about $100$x longer.

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 3, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] //  N // Timing
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 2, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] //  N // Timing
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] //  N // Timing
(* Output:
{0.278759, 816592.}
{0.244387, 3465.51}
{0.002092, 8.51496} *)
```

This difference is progressively exacerbated as $x$ gets close to $1$.

By inspection, the functional form of all three expressions are quite similar. The only
notable difference is that the last one can be written in terms of $\mbox{}_2F_1$:

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 3, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, x] // Timing
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 2, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, x] // Timing
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, x] // Timing
```

It can be confirm that this is the source of the slowdown by trying:

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 3, 1}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] // N // Timing
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 2, 1}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] // N // Timing
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1, 1}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] // N // Timing
(* Output:
{0.006002, 1737.01}
{0.005309, 8.51496}
{0.005624, 0.0242938} *)
```

In this case, they all take about as long, since all three (in terms of general $x$) can be written in terms of $\mbox{}_2F_1$.

Is there a way to speed up the calculations for when $n \neq 2$?

Comment: `RepeatedTiming[HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, #, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, 99/100] // FullSimplify // N] & /@ Range[3, 1, -1]`

Comment: The use of `FullSimplify` helps a bit, but there is still a huge difference in runtime, that is more and more noticeable for $x$ closer to $1$. Try your suggested code with $x=999/1000$ for example.

Comment: If you want to be evaluating a given function multiple times, then I suggest this: `func[x_] =  FunctionExpand@ HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 3, 2}, {1 - 30, 1 + 30}, x];` with `Set` (`=`); then use `func[x]`. Redefine `func[x]` when you switch functions. For instance, `func[999/1000] // N`. One might be worried about numerical precision with this workaround. With your examples, it doesn't seem to matter much.